# How do I change the default command prompt directory in windows 7?

Tags: windows, command-line

When I open command prompt it's now defaulting to the user folder rather than system32 as it used to.

How do I permanently change it back to system32 like it's supposed to be rather than just a temporary CD command?

I have read that this change has occurred due to an installed program changing an environment variable but not sure how to correct it.

This is a windows 7 machine so there is no right click "open in file location" setting.

Thank you.

Comment: Opening to USERS has been that way for a while. Even with PATH CompSpec set the System32, USERS is still used by CMD.   It is not any kind of an impediment to me.

Comment: @John, not so in Windows 20H2, v. 19042.985 - it opens to System32.

Comment: Even in 21H1 CMD opens in USERS.  System32 is protected and I think Microsoft has set things to prevent issues

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Using Windows 20H2 v. 19042.985, if I launch cmd as administrator, System32 is opened. If launch normally, then USERS is opened.

Comment: Command Prompt will always open in the users's folder. This is so by design since Windows 7 and up. If you run Command Prompt as Administrator, it changes to %windir%\system32. So run CMD as administrator is one way to get it working.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - You must be running the command prompt as an Administrator in that case.  The default starting location of Command Prompt has not changed between Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound, no, for whatever reason, when I hit the Windows key, type "CMD" and Enter, it opens at the Sytem32 folder. And I'm not pressing Ctrl-Shift, nor does the CMD prompt have Administrative privilege. This is what I observe, not theoretical.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766546/setting-a-default-path-in-command-prompt) explains the difference in behavior

Answer (score 5):

For [Windows 10, there are multiple ways to change the default CMD path](https://techsupportwhale.com/change-default-directory-in-command-prompt/); one of these might also work on archaic versions.

- Using a Windows shortcut:

  - Right-click a folder (or desktop).
  - Select *New > Shortcut*.
  - In *Type the location of the item,* enter `cmd.exe`, click *Next* and *Finish*.
  - Right-click the new shortcut and select *Properties*.
  - In *Start in:*, enter `C:\Windows\System32` or other path.
- Using a Registry change:

  - Open *Regedit*.
  - Browse to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` (or copy/paste that key into the location bar).
  - Rigjht-click the right pane and select *New > String Value*.
  - Name the new REG_SZ *Autorun*.
  - Double-click the new value and enter `cd /d C:\Windows\System32` or other path for the value.

Comment: The registry edit works but keeps being flagged for deletion any time I run a scan of the machine. Regardless this is a new issue as command prompt used to previously default to the system32 folder without this change being necessary. Like I said in the original post, I've read elsewhere that this change was caaused by an enviroment variable alteration. How do I ensure the enviroment variables are correct so this is fixed in the process?

Comment: Still looking for enviroment variables since DrMoishe Pippik's solution is only a work around and not an actual fix.

Comment: It works after creating the Command Processor key plus the registry entry

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 from DrMoishe - creating a shortcut - didn't work on Windows 11 when running the command prompt in admin mode.

Following the link to the [article](https://techsupportwhale.com/change-default-directory-in-command-prompt/) he cited, there is another similar option that worked in my case.

1. Find the current, or create a new command prompt shortcut. I did a right click on the Command prompt icon in start menu, and clicked find location.
2. Right click the shortcut, and click properties
3. Change the target folder. It should have `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe` or something like it, in there already. Add a space, `/k`, another space, then a change directory command (cd) and your desired start location in "". Here is an example...

`%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k "cd C:\somepath\here"`

That will do the trick