# Command prompt - initial current-directory setting

Tags: windows, command-line

Following an OS-reinstall (now Win 10 Home build 19042) I now find that when I start `cmd.exe` from a desktop "shortcut", the current directory on one of my drives is not the root directory as in the past, but a frequently-used directory.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: Show current directory for all drives
FOR %%b IN (%alphabet%) DO IF EXIST %%b:. FOR /f "tokens=2*delims= " %%h IN ('dir %%b:. ^|find "\"') DO ECHO %%i
```

Running this batch when the shortcut has started a `cmd.exe` instance yields:

```
c:\106x
D:\
E:\
F:\
L:\
M:\neo
N:\
U:\
V:\
```

I know about `C:` - it's the "start in" directory. It's the `M:` directory that's the problem. Whereas it's a directory I often use, in the past (before the re-install) I believe the current directory for `M:` was the root, same as all of the other drives.

I've not been able to find any setting that appears to specify the directory - there's no mention of `M:\neo` in the registry.

After two solid days of trying to restore my system to my settings, this one's got me stumped.

### Update 20210702T113000Z

Having survived at least three restarts, the problem has now conveniently disappeared.

Comment: Where cmd.exe opens depends in part whether you run it as Administrator or regular user. You might look at that.

Comment: In the properties section of every Windows shortcut, there is a place to enter a folder for the current directory.  Is the folder name stored there by any chance?

Comment: There are a number of ways to change the folder in which CMD opens: https://superuser.com/questions/1653018/how-do-i-change-the-default-command-prompt-directory-in-windows-7/1653024#1653024

Comment: @John I disable UAC and run the shortcut using the "as administrator" option. Having survived at least three restarts, the problem has now conveniently disappeared.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket The "Start in" option was set to "C:\106x". There appears to be no facility to set the current-directory on other drives, although it would be theoretically possible to run a process that would.  Having survived at least three restarts, the problem has now conveniently disappeared.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The problem isn't the start directory - the specified directory (C:\106x) was indeed selected. The problem*was* that for no apparent reason, the `M:` drive decided to select `\neo` instead of the `expected `root` directory.  Having survived at least three restarts, the problem has now conveniently disappeared.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket : Appreciate the  attempt to clarify date/time. I live in UTC+08:00 & most SX users appear to live in UTC-08:00 to UTC-5:00 so an unadorned date can be misleading, hence I use ISO8601. Or something like ISO8601. I see no reason for using the "T" - it appears to be just noise to me. Likewise the "Z" which should be implicit if no TZ modifier is supplied. Equally, the seconds digits are rarely relevant (this case for instance) so to me can be omitted. Had my edit occurred 3 hours later it would be July 3rd to me but 2nd to most users which could very well be confusing

Comment: It's all good. :)  I was just trying to simply it because after a day or two the exact time details would be irrelevant.  Ideally, SE would  have some mechanism to enter such timestamps to auto-reflect the system timezone defined on which the content is being viewed.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior indicates that the `cmd.exe` process is inheriting an environment block containing an `=M:` environment variable with the value `M:\neo`. Such hidden environment variables [are used internally by the command processor](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100506-00/?p=14133) to keep track of the current directory for each drive. If Explorer is passing them on to the new `cmd.exe`, that suggests that Explorer was (perhaps indirectly) launched from a command prompt whose last current directory on the M drive was `M:\neo`. I can reproduce this behavior with these steps:

1. Open a command prompt to `M:\neo`.
2. Terminate Explorer, e.g. with `taskkill /im explorer.exe /f`.
3. Restart `explorer` from the open command prompt. This instance of Explorer inherits all the command processor's environment variables.
4. Launch a new command prompt from Explorer, e.g. with a shortcut or the Run dialog. This prompt's current directory on the M drive will also be `M:\neo`.

If UAC is disabled, it is conceivable that a Task Manager instance launched from the command line could also be part of "the chain of custody of your environment block," having been used to restart Explorer at some point. (Note: Not tested, since I have UAC on.)

You can verify that Explorer is passing on the per-drive current directory variable by launching PowerShell instead and evaluating `${env:=M:}`, since PowerShell itself will not set these variables. But if the variable is absent/empty, it is possible that the current directory is being affected by a script invoked by [command processor AutoRun commands](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433). It would be possible to see those in the Registry or disable them temporarily by launching `cmd /d` from the Run dialog.

I understand that the problem has gone away for you, but in case it comes back (and for others' benefit), you can try to investigate environment inheritance by looking at the process tree in [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). If the process that launched Explorer is still running, it will show as Explorer's parent in the tree on the left and you will be able to see many details about it. But in the likely event that the parent process has ended, you would need to [enable process auditing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/command-line-process-auditing), reboot, and trace through instances of event 4688 to figure out what chain of processes (probably involving a batch script) created the instance of Explorer that is currently running.

Comment: Good information here. All `cmd` instances were started from the shortcut. My observation : if you are fast enough, you can start a `cmd` session from the shortcut & the two envvars `FPS_*` will be missing. "Edge" then appears to terminate and restart `explorer` with these two new envvars established. It would appear that "Edge" jumps in at random times & again terminates/restarts `explorer` - the screen icons disappear briefly & then re-appear. Often, focus is lost from the application that had focus, cursor-arrow returns to white (I set it yellow) & CCleaner reports a browser-close.